# Efficiently get permutation of 3 numpy arrays of differing sizes and types

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have 3 numpy arrays of arbitrary size and type as indicated:

> time (datetime), lats (float64), longs (float64)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

time  = np.asarray(['2018-05-01T00:30:00.000000000','2018-05-01T01:30:00.000000000','2018-05-01T02:30:00.000000000', '2018-05-01T03:30:00.000000000'], dtype='<M8[ns]')
lats  = np.asarray([-90. , -89.5, -89. , -88.5, -88. , -87.5, -87. , -86.5, -86. ,-85.5])
longs = np.asarray([-180., -179.3, -178.7 , -178.1, -177.5  , -176.8, -176.2 , -175.6, -175., -174.3, -173.7 , -173.1 ,-172.5 , -171.8, -171.2 , -170.6, -170., -169.3])
```

And 1 array which holds the values that correspond of the flattened and ordered permutation of the three arrays, giving it a length of:

```
length = len(time)*len(lats)*len(longs)
values = np.asarray(range(length), dtype='float64')
```

Here the values are arbitrary but the index is important. I'm seeking to build a flattened data set that holds all the data ordered on time, lats, longs - in that order, as there should be len(longs) values for each lat. Below is my working code:

```
master = pd.DataFrame(np.array(np.meshgrid(time, longs, lats)).T.reshape(-1,3), columns = ['datetime', 'long', 'lat'])
master['values'] = values
print master.head()
```

[image: DataFrame]

While this works OK, I have to convert datetime column back to a timestamp:

```
master['datetime'] = master['datetime'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
print master
```

[image]

This process of reshaping the data, flattening it, then converting between types is too slow and comes at a high computational load. Is there a more efficient method to achieve my desired data structure?

Comment: What are your typical array sizes like?

Comment: Only long/lat vary as time is always 24, but it can be from 10 up to a couple hundred, sometimes more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid a lot of your low-level numpy manipulations by using MultiIndex.from_product, and it has the advantage that you won't lose type information.  This bypasses the very slow pd.to_datetime call.  For example:

```
time = pd.date_range("2018-05-01", freq="30min", periods=24).values
lats = np.linspace(-90, -80, 1000)
longs = np.linspace(-180, -170, 1000)

length = len(time)*len(lats)*len(longs)
values = np.arange(length, dtype='float64')
```

which gives a length of 24 M, and then:

and then

```
In [48]: %time df = pd.Series(values, 
         index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([time, lats, longs], 
               names=["datetime", "lat", "long"])).reset_index(name='values')
Wall time: 1.38 s

In [49]: df.head()
Out[49]: 
    datetime   lat       long  values
0 2018-05-01 -90.0 -180.00000     0.0
1 2018-05-01 -90.0 -179.98999     1.0
2 2018-05-01 -90.0 -179.97998     2.0
3 2018-05-01 -90.0 -179.96997     3.0
4 2018-05-01 -90.0 -179.95996     4.0
```